# Firebase database still have slight downloads even after goOffline() and keepSynced(false)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase database still have slight downloads even after goOffline() and keepSynced(false).

I just want to get the data once. Then I save it to SharedPreferences.  Next time user run the app it will check if the data exists in SharedPreferences, if it does then no need to get from Firebase again.

But in the Firebase dashboard I keep on seeing increased ammount of downloads (like 10KB) after some couple hours.
How do I completely turn off this Firebase? Am I missing something?

MainActivity:

```html
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ---- SOME PSEUDO CODE ----
        if (mySharedPreferences.has(theValue)) {
            //already has the value. 
            //No need to get from Firebase.
        }
        else { //doesn't have the value, so get it from Firebase.
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOnline(); //-->ONLINE

            DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("someNode");
            myRef.child("datax").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    mySharedPreferences.set(theValue);
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOffline(); //-->OFFLINE
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOffline(); //-->OFFLINE
                }
            });
            myRef.keepSynced(false); //-->NOT SYNCYED
        }
    }
```

Comment: The usage dashboard shows traffic from all sources, including clients and the console itself. To check what traffic your client is having, [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) and check logcat.

Comment: I'll see it later.  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot completely turn off Firebase as long as you use are using the database. What can you see in Firebase Console is traffic that is gathered from all sources. Even if you have active listeners or only the users are accessing your app, all that traffic is recorded there. Even the usage of Firebase Console is considered usage and is present as traffic there. As Frank said, to have a more details view about your traffic you need to enable debug logging and check what happens in the logcat.

Comment: I see.  I wasn't aware even the usage of the console is also counted as traffic.