# Firestore Pricing - Does The CRUD In Firebase Console Matter?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am understand that we have been charges for every read, write and delete operation, but my question are these operation also being counted in the firebase console?

Sometimes, we just wanna see the data through firebase console, and when click at the collection, it will automatically display the documents data and also sub-collection of the documents. Are we gonna get charged through activity in console too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are these operation also being counted in the firebase console?

Yes, all read, write or delete operations performed even from the cosole are counted.

> Are we gonna get charged through activity in console too?

Yes.

Comment: hurm. can't play much in firebase console after this.

Comment: That's the way the pricing model of Firestore works. The traffic that is made in the console is also counted. You can also take a look at my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47466233/firebase-database-still-have-slight-downloads-even-after-gooffline-and-keepsyn/47468112#47468112).

Comment: @AlexMamo what about batch operations (transactions)? Counted as one operation? I'm guess it makes no difference and the operations inside are still counted individually?

Comment: @Dominic No, every operation within a transaction is counted separately.